# Understanding parameters in regression for a Singh-Maddala response variable

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to understand the use of regression using a response variable (y) with a Singh-Maddala distribution.

To make a regression with many variables I'm using this code:

```
median_y =  median(datos[,y])
Formula = as.formula(paste0(y," ~ ",paste(variables,collapse=" + ")))
fit2 <- vglm(Formula, sinmad(lss = FALSE, iscale=median_y)
, data = datos, trace = FALSE, control = vglm.control(maxit=100) )
```

I don't understand the iscale parameter. Using the median of the "y" is the right choice (I put arbitrarly) or there is a method to set the parameters in order to make the best aproximation?

I mean, in the normal distribution, the parameters are easy, there is the mean ($\mu$) and sd ($\sigma$) and in z distribution, there is 0 and 1. And the glm estimates the mean of the normal distribution ($\mu$,$\sigma$), there is no ($\mu$) parameter to put in glm function (it's not necesary). But in Singh-Maddala does not, there are three parameters and, to me, it's difficult to translate real data to those parameters.

Comment: It would be better for you to simply better for former question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637421/use-of-singh-maddala-regression  than asking a new one!